# How to declare bi-dimensional array of certain size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For declaring an array of length n in Javascript I'm using this code:

```
const n = 5;
const myArray = Array(n).fill(false);

> [false, false, false, false, false]
```

But how to declare an bi-dimensional array, for example anotherArray(m,n) ?

seems that

```
 const anotherArray = Array(m, n).fill(false);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method to change all elements in an array to a static value and then using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method again fill the each element with a new array like:

```js
const fill = (m, v = 0) => Array(m).fill(v),
  createBDArr = (m, n) => fill(m).map(() => fill(n, false));

console.log( createBDArr(5, 2) )
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) takes for non primitive values the **same** object reference.

To overcome this, you need to create independent arrays.

```js
const
    length = 5,
    array = Array.from({ length }, _ => Array.from({ length }, _ => false));

array[2][1] = true;
console.log(array);
```